# socket.io client side not receiving message by room

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, android-room, message

`I am currently working on a project using socket.io version 4.7.2 with Node.js version 20.10.0. The server side appears to receive the 'joinRoom' event successfully, but I am encountering issues when trying to send a message from the server to the client using the 'test' event. Below is the relevant code snippets

```js
// Server Side
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom', () => {
        console.log('starting');
        socket.join('room1');
        socket.to('room1').emit('test', 'Welcome!');
        console.log('ended');
    });
});
// Client Side
socket.on('test', (data) => {
    console.log(' ~ file: newLogin.js:55 ~ socket.on ~ data:', data);
});
```

`When the joinRoom event is triggered, the server logs "starting" and "ended," but the client does not seem to receive the test event. Strangely, if I use socket.emit instead of socket.to('room1').emit, the client does receive the message.`

Any insights into what might be causing this issue or suggestions for debugging would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!